# Is there a way with Excel Formulas to Sum up a column with the values above the referenced column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example say I have this data set:

| ◢ | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 0 |  |
| **2** | 2 | 0 |  |
| **3** | 2 | 1 |  |

What I want to do is put a formula into column C that sums all of the values from Column A if they are in the current row or above, from the sum of the values in Colum B that are in the current row or above.

So if the formula was run on row 2 the sum of Column A would be 2 and the sum of Column B would be 0 making the value of Column C 2.

Or if the formula was run on row 3 Columns A's sum would be 4, Column B's sum would be 1, so Column C's Value would be 3.

Is this something Formulas can even do?

Comment: Transform to the Table and enter the SUM function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C1 and drag down:

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)-SUM($B$1:B1)
```

It locks the top reference and the bottom reference is dynamic.

[image]

Or you can use SCAN if you have it:

```
=SCAN(0,A1:A3-B1:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))
```

This creates and array of the difference at each row then keeps a running total.  This has the advantage of being able to put the formula in one cell and have it "spill" down automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, for some reason I was thinking it would be more complicated than that.